# Logstash doesn't start as a service

Tags: chef-infra, logstash

starting logstash as a service with chef via

```
service 'logstash' do
  supports :status => true, :restart => true, :reload => true
  action [:enable, :restart]
end
```

I get

```
$ systemctl status logstash
logstash.service - LSB: Starts Logstash as a daemon.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/logstash)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2016-08-25 15:33:11 UTC; 1min 42s ago
  Process: 3235 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/logstash start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

using `systemctl restart logstash`

```
$ systemctl status logstash
logstash.service - LSB: Starts Logstash as a daemon.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/logstash)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-08-25 15:35:03 UTC; 4s ago
  Process: 3769 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/logstash stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3773 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/logstash start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/logstash.service
           └─3780 /bin/java -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=7...
```

which then causes logstash to run properly

`journalctl -u logstash` (before the manual restart) gives

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2016-08-25 15:15:03 UTC. --
Aug 25 15:26:58 machine_ip systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts Logstash as a daemon....
Aug 25 15:26:58 machine_ip logstash[3300]: logstash started.
Aug 25 15:26:58 machine_ip systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts Logstash as a daemon..
```

what is wrong with it?

Comment: It's really difficult to trace and error here because it __should__ work. Is your logstash service enabled? When you just start the service, what is the output of `journalctl -u logstash.service`?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: Have you checked the unit file?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using systemd to control initd scripts instead of just writing a unit file?

Comment: I have no idea what a unit file is :/

Comment: Which chef version ? which logstash version ? which distribution and version ?

Comment: chef 11.12, logstash 2.3.4 on centos 7

Comment: Are you sure you need `action [:enable, :restart]` and not `action [:enable, :start]`?

Answer (score 1):

[what you are really looking for here is](https://docs.chef.io/resource_service.html):

:start

Start a service, and keep it running until stopped or disabled.

:restart

will only restart it when it detects a need to, which I believe varies in some services.

using :start will make sure it starts up the first time.